# Why doesn't sorted() nor max() return the highest value of a list?

Tags: python

I have a `string` of numbers and I'm looking for the highest number in the string. I've tried to use the `max()` function which returned number 6 while the highest number in the string is 542. Then I used `sorted()` to check again and it returned 6 as the final number instead of 542. How is this possible?

Here is the code and the string of numbers:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    return sorted(numbers.split())

high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6")
```

Comment: "6" is indeed the highest *string* in your list, considered alphabetically.  Just because you named it `numbers` doesn't magically cause Python to turn the strings into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that the numbers are concatenated into one string. If you run the code below, which searches for the largest number in an array of `int` (integers), the program will output the number 542.

```
nums = [4, 5, 29, 54, 4, 0, -214, 542, -64, 1, -3, 6, -6]
def high_and_low(numbers):
    return max(numbers)

print(high_and_low(nums))
```

Note: There is also no need to call `sorted` since `max` will find the largest number regardless if the numbers are sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Because the items are string! string items are compared different than integers. You can use `key` argument to specify the way you want `max` , `min`, `sorted` , `.sort` work. Every item in iterable goes into that callable (here `int`) then the results are get compared.

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    return max(numbers.split(), key=int)


print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
```